# All countable spaces that are first countable are also second countable.

Tags: general-topology

Can someone please verify whether:  a) the assertion is correct and b) if the assertion is correct if the proof is correct.

All countable spaces that are first countable are also second countable.

Proof:  Let (X, T) be a countable topological space that is first countable.  Since X is countable there exists a local basis at each point in X.  There are countably many of these points in X.  Therefore, the countable union of all the local bases (which are themselves countable) is countable. This union forms a basis for the space (since 1. X is clearly covered by the Basis and 2. if we intersect a base element with another base element we get an open set.  Let x be an element of that open set then we know that there is a local basis containing x that is contained that set and that local basis element is an element of the total basis).

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: Great.  Thank you.

Comment: Try with lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R }$. First countable but not second countable

Comment: @Sam How the assertion is correct. See above comment.

Comment: R is not countable Aman.

Comment: @AmanPandey The question is about **countable** spaces.

Comment: Ohh yes. I didn't get  attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is correct, but the proof is not: you're confusing (as often happens) "a base for *some* topology on $X$" (which is what you check), with "a base for the given topology on $X$", which is what you need (and is asked for).

So suppose $\{\mathcal{B}_n(x), n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a countable local base at $x$ for $X$.
Define $\mathcal{B}=\bigcup \{\mathcal{B}_n(x): x \in X\}$, which is indeed a countable union of countable sets, so a countable family of open sets of $X$; Now,
let $O$ be open in $X$ and $x \in O$. There is some $U \in \mathcal{B}_n(x)$ such that $x \in U \subseteq O$ by the definition of being a local base at $x$. But clearly also $U \in \mathcal{B}$ and we have a member $B_x$ of $\mathcal{B}$ ($U$ from before) with $x \in B_x \subseteq O$, and this says that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$ (it implies we can write all open sets of $X$ as unions of sets from $\mathcal{B}$: write $O = \bigcup \{B_x: x \in O\}$, e.g. and this union property makes it a base for $X$(!)) and we're done. It's pretty clear by definition, really.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the "*confusing (as often happens)...*" statement. The topology of $X$ and first countability are given, the OP proved that **the same topology** is also second countable. And his/her argument is basically the same as yours. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Sam my point is that he dis *not* show that. He shows the two axioms for being some base. You need $\forall O \text{ open }: \forall x \in O: \exists U \in \mathcal{B}: x \in U \subseteq O$, not the two axioms.

Comment: @Sam Suppose you were asked to show that all rational intervals form a base for the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$, and the argument you get is: 1. the rational intervals cover the reals. 2. They are closed under intersections. Then you'd also say the answer proved the wrong thing.

Comment: Don’t I just need to show that there exists a countable basis in this space ( to show second countable).  I found that basis ie union of local bases and demonstrated that that union is countable and is basis.

Comment: When I’m discussing the local base and then the actual base it’s with reference to that particular topology.  So when I refer to open sets I mean open sets in T.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see your point but I also see as obvious that the topology generated by the union of all local basis coincides with the topology that was there to define that local base in the first place: the open sets are the unions of the exact same sets. Maybe that's what your argument proves, I have no objections to that.

Comment: @AlexM The criterion you cite is *not* to check it is a base for that particular topology, but that it defines *some* topology on the set (i.e. to define a topology). The fact that that a union of local bases for a topology is a total base for the same topology, is the point of the exercise to let you realise, I think. It's indeed a simple fact, but requires a small argument, which I gave.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.   Ok, thank you I understand what you mean.